# Windowed lag/delta with Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

First of all, I'm pretty new to spark, so apologies if I'm missing the obvious!

I'm developing a POC using Spark, which consumes a stream of data from Apache Kafka. My first goal was general moving averages which was simple using the 'window' function in Spark, and calculate some averages based on some keys.

My next goal is to calculate the 'delta' since the last window. So, if I have a parameter call 'noise', the 'window' function calculates avg(noise). But I want to also include the the delta of avg(noise) between the current window the the previous window.

I tried using the `lag` function, however it does not look like it is supposed:

`Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets`

My question is, does Spark Structure Streaming provide some way to calculate this out of the box? I've contemplated using `MapGroupsWithStateFunction` which I think might work, but if there is a built in approach that is obviously preferable.

My bit of code for this is:

```
WindowSpec w = Window.partitionBy(functions.col("window.start"), functions.col("keyName")).orderBy(functions.col("window.start"));

Dataset<Row> outputDS = inputDataset.withWatermark("timeStamp", "1 days")
        .groupBy(functions.col("keyName"), functions.window(functions.col("timeStamp"), "1 hours", "1 hours"))
        .avg("noise").withColumn("delta", functions.lag("avg(noise)", 1).over(w));
```